# Google app engine maintain parent child relation in backup

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i took backup of two models on Google app engine , one model is the parent of other, now i have downloaded the backup and reading the backup using

```
records.RecordsReader
```

as described in

http://blog.robert.je/post/google-app-engine-datastore-backups-part-2

however i can read individual entities only. How can i get the child of an entity from the backup data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say you can read "individual entities only". The relationship between an ancestor and its children in the GAE datastore is maintained via the key: a child entity includes the path of the parent in its key. Since that is maintained when you restore from the datastore backup, the parent/child relationship is also carried over.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i mean lets say i have entiy A and its child entity B , so i can individually read A or B , i cant get B while reading A. to get by key i will have to scan through all the backup files to get the child.